# Selenium/Python: Not able to find an element using any of the find_element_by_* methods

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a strange challenge that I am facing - likely has to do with my inadequate understanding of html.

I need to extract some data from a web-site. But I am somehow not able to get past the login step - despite having used similar code for several other such applications in the past. I am just not able to locate the username or password element using any of the get_element_by_*() methods. I have spent the last 24 hours trying various things and researching things. I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong here - but can't figure out what. I have very similar code with which I am able to login to a different web-site (http://courtbooking.bayclubs.com) without any trouble.

HELP! I am copying-n-pasting the relevant portion of my code

```
url = "https://www.ussquash.com/serve/?program=login"
inp_username = "my-username"
inp_password = "my-password"
try:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
except:
    print("No web driver")
    exit()

try:
    driver.get(url)
except:
    print("Could not load URL")
    exit()

time.sleep(wait_time_in_seconds)

try:
    #user = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
    user = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
except Exception as e:
    print("No username element, error {}".format(e))
    exit()
else:
    print("Username element found")

try:
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("loginpass")
except Exception as e:
    print("No password element, error {}".format(e))
    exit()
else:
    print("Password element found")

try:
    signon_button = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_in_seconds).until(
                            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-primary login-btn")))
except:
    print("No signon element")
    exit()
else:
    print("Signon element found")


print("Logging in with username: %s, password: %s", inp_username, inp_password)
user.clear()
user.send_keys(inp_username)
password.clear()
password.send_keys(inp_password)
signon_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the website is using iFrames for the login part, so first you need to switch to the iframe with

`driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)`.

Then select the elements you want. Hope this helps [[Link]](https://computerrecipes.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/selenium-webdriver-interact-with-an-element-inside-an-iframe/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nash. That did the trick. I ended up having to do a trial and error because it was not straight-forward to understand if iFrames are nested or if it is a flat set of iFrames. Now after solving this problem, I am stuck in another place where I am not able to find the right element - likely has to do with the same issue, but my "current window" seems to be in a place from where I am not able to switch to the right frame. If you have any pointers to understanding this properly, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: Hello JoyOfCoding, check out this [LINK](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html) maybe it'll help you a bit more.